# Lock a byobu session with password?

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen, byobu

I used to leave my `byobu` sessions detached on a server. I want to lock the session to prevent other users (root account) accessing my session.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU screen (one backend that byobu can use, along with `tmux`) has the lockscreen functionality. Have a look at the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) to see what it does. The default binding is `C-a C-x`.

With regard to your trying to lock root out, it's rather [pointless](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2459/250). What you can try is to find a locking program that let you set a password and hope that root doesn't know about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the default binding works with byobu. 

The password by default in ubuntu on a locked byobu is the same as the user's.

Comment: Great that this works for you. Just be aware that it's not protected against root ;)

Comment: I share root account with a colleague, and he uses my screens without permission. i will launch as my normal user and inside do `sudo su`

Answer (score 3):

Byobu now also supports a `tmux` backend, in addition to `screen`.

For `tmux`, you can issue the `lock-session` (to lock the entire session and all attached clients), or the `lock-client` command, to just lock the current client.